# App crashes when using UIScrollView but only when paging (content created in storyboard)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have this situation. I have VC in which I want to show scroll view which will present a set of sub screens for that VC. The user should be able to scroll through the sub screens (in paging manner). The number and the basic layout of the subscreens is always the same so I wanted to create the content in storyboard. So I did it like this:

1. I have implemented container view in the main VC
2. I have embedded new VC in that container view and changed it property fixed size to my custom size (7 x width of the container view, height of the container view)
3. I have implemented UIScrollView in the view of the new VC (matched the frame of the new UIScrollView with new VCs view frame)
4. Implemented 7 UIViews (size == container view size) in the UIScrollView so that they stand after another, filling the entire content view of the UIScrollView
5. Added constraints of width, height and position for every sub screen view (in respect to the scroll view)
6. Turned on paging

My thinking was that when layout ended the container view will force the new VC to resize it self to his bounds, but the constraints of the sub screen view will keep the content view of the UIScrollerView as it is in the storyboard. And I was right, when the scrolling is disabled everything works fine and looks like I want it to look and it scrolls fine, but when I turn on paging and scroll something wired happens and the app crashes.

I have done many logging and the numbers for the scrollview bounds, contentsize, rect look fine, as they should look

Anybody has any idea, what am I doing wrong and what could be wrong?
Thanks in advance...

[image: screenshot:]

Stack trace: 
Thread 0 Crashed:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x387211f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3878b792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x386d1fd8 abort + 72
3   MyApp                           0x001a8f36 uncaught_exception_handler + 22
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2d5be2d4 __handleUncaughtException + 576
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3815ef50 _objc_terminate() + 172
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37a171c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37a16d28 __cxa_rethrow + 96
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3815ee12 objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2d4f1f80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 636
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2d4f1cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x3241765e GSEventRunModal + 134
12  UIKit                           0x2fe3d168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  MyApp                           0x0017a530 main (main.m:16)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3866bab4 start + 0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2d5bdfce __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3815ecca objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2d5bdf10 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
3   QuartzCore                      0x2fa4e644 CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool) + 308
4   QuartzCore                      0x2fa4e44a -[CALayer setBounds:] + 106
5   UIKit                           0x2fe253d4 -[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 324
6   UIKit                           0x2fe33414 -[UIScrollView setBounds:] + 1060
7   UIKit                           0x2fdf9182 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 554
8   UIKit                           0x2ff750da -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollWithUpdateTime:] + 2970
9   QuartzCore                      0x2faa5dee CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 94
10  QuartzCore                      0x2faa5b98 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 340
11  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x3283f758 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 100
12  IOKit                           0x2e2a844c IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 244
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2d57def4 __CFMachPortPerform + 132
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2d588ab2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2d588a4e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2d587222 __CFRunLoopRun + 1394
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2d4f1f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2d4f1cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
19  GraphicsServices                0x3241765e GSEventRunModal + 134
20  UIKit                           0x2fe3d168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
21  MyApp                           0x0017a530 main (main.m:16)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x3866bab2 tlv_initializer + 2
```

Comment: What's the crash message ? log ?

Comment: Nothing, SIGABRT in main.m, I will post crash stack from the device

Comment: It seams like scrollview bounds cant be set, but I can log them in my code and they look ok

Comment: Nothing in the console ? stack trace ?

Comment: I have edited the post with stack trace

Comment: Was there nothing about the first line ?

Comment: Crashed because of unhanded exception, so there should be the exception output ?

Comment: When I am connected to the debugger I get nothing, just SIGABRT in main.m, and no stack... The log that I posted I get directly from the device, when app crashes and I am not connected to the debugger

Comment: symbolicate it ? Do you have the console window open in Xcode ? That should say something ? If it doesn't you may be accessing released memory. Turn zombies on ? Xcode > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > run > Diagnostics > enable zombie ojects

Comment: There is no code for this, just IB, In code I just log things for debug. Anyways, if I turn off all the constrains, and set the content size and the frame of the scroll view in code, everything works, so the problem is somewhere in setting the constraints... It seams that paging is using something in background that is not documented. From documentation paging uses bounds property of the scroll view, and from my log I can see that setting bounds raises exception so something is not right with the bounds. But when I NSLog bounds they look ok.